# How to understand configuration files syntax?

Tags: etc, configure

Now I know this is a little abstract but how does one know how do edit a config file for example `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` how do you know what syntax is allowed and what not?

Comment: Have you tried `man logind.conf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration file formats vary between different configuration files. You may want to conduct a google search for a tutorial on the format you wish to use. For `.conf` files in `/etc/systemd`, I found this wiki page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd